# How can I online stream from my iPad Air to an older model Viera TV without Apple TV?

Tags: ipad

How can I connect my iPad Air to an older Panasonic Viera TC-L37e3 to stream a YouTube video? What app do I need, if any?  Can I use a HDMI adaptor?

Comment: I think the only way to do what you want will be with a [Google Chromecast](https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/chromecast/?utm_source=chromecast.com).  Have you tried one of those?

Comment: No, I haven't.  I'll look into it.  I think it's time to upgrade, and get a newer tv.  Thank you for your response.  Happy July 4th!

Answer (score 1):

I take a glance at Panasonic Viera TC-L37e3 manual and as I understood it has DLNA feature. Have you try to use it? Because there are several streaming apps for iPad working with DLNA devices (Infuse, nPlayer, ArkMC, VLC). They give you a possibility to wirelessly connect your iPad and TV.
The only problem is if they work with Youtube videos. I definitely know that ArkMC streams Youtube videos, but what about others, I doubt.